# Makefile variable shared between custom packages for openwrt

Tags: makefile, openwrt, shared-variable

While adding custom packages, package A is using Makefile variable that needs to be updated (or not) by other package B, however package B is not mandatory for compiling package A. In other words, if configuration selects package B in that case shared Makefile variable be populated and values can be seen by other packages.

**Package A**

$(variable1)

**package B**

variable1 := "-Dxyz -Dabc"

I tried with setting empty "variable1" in rules.mk which is not working. Appreciate if anyone can point me existing examples for same.

Comment: Are Package A and Package B part of the same build?

Comment: @JohnBollinger both packages are the part of same build environment, but i want to build single package A, without building package B.

Comment: I have been thinking about this, but I just don't have enough knowledge about openwrt's configuration and build framework to answer the question in its present form.  The answer is likely to hinge on details of how that works, and of the way it sets up makefiles.  Generally speaking, one makefile has no visibility on variables set in other makefiles, but there are ways to work around that.

Comment: okay. Thanks @JohnBollinger for your inputs.